# How to show lens studio lenses or cloths made in blender in android app using ar core?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, blender, arcore

I'm working on a AR project like try on tech which basically shows the cloth on real time human body through camera. But I'm stuck at how to carry out the live try on feature on android studio. Like if I have design the tshirt in A body pose in blender so how I can make that tshirt to show in real time on human through camera. Please help me into this.